# pybind11 speeding up function calls

Tags: python, c++, performance, pybind11

I have several C++ function objects that I construct in Python using pybind11 and then pass these objects from Python to another C++ function which calls them.  Since these functions have state, they do not go through the pybind11 optimization for stateless python functions and the performance is very slow.

I can workaround this with an ugly hack that returns the pointer of the created C++ object to Python, which then passes the pointer back to the caller C++ function. However, I was hoping there was a cleaner, more maintainable way to do this.

Here is some code that replicates this (import_call_execute embeds a Python process and runs it) based on:  https://pythonextensionpatterns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugging/debug_in_ide.html

The first python program below takes 163 millisecs on my machine and the second takes only 0.5 milliseconds

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#include "py_import_call_execute.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace pybind11::literals;

namespace py = pybind11;

class TestFunc {
public:
    TestFunc(int a): _a(a) {}

    int operator()(int b) const {
        return _a + b;
    }

    size_t get_ptr() {
        return (size_t)this;
    }
private:
    int _a;
};

int test_dummy_function(const std::function<int(int)> &f) {
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        sum += f(i);
    }
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);

    cout << "sum: " << sum << " time: " << duration.count() / 1000.0 << " milliseconds" << endl;

    return sum;
}

int test_dummy_function2(std::size_t ptr) {
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    TestFunc* f = reinterpret_cast<TestFunc*>(ptr);

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        sum += (*f)(i);
    }
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);

    cout << "sum: " << sum << " time: " << duration.count() / 1000.0 << " milliseconds" << endl;

    return sum;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(pybind_testing, m) {
    py::class_<TestFunc>(m, "TestFunc")
    .def(py::init<int>(), "a"_a)
    .def("__call__", &TestFunc::operator(), "b"_a = 3)
    .def("get_ptr", &TestFunc::get_ptr);

    m.def("test_dummy_function", test_dummy_function);
    m.def("test_dummy_function2", test_dummy_function2);
 }

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    argc = 4;
    const char *argv2[] = {
            "python",
            "/Users/sal/Developer/coatbridge/testing/pybind11",
            "test_pybind11",
            "test_pybind11"};
    return import_call_execute(argc, argv2);
}
```

Python function 1:

```
import pybind_testing as pt

def test_pybind11():
    test_func = pt.TestFunc(2)
    pt.test_dummy_function(test_func)
```

Python function 2:

```
import pybind_testing as pt

def test_pybind11():
    test_func = pt.TestFunc(2)
    pt.test_dummy_function2(test_func.get_ptr())
```

Answer (score 2):

The poor performance has nothing to do with pybind11 or Python.  It's slow because you're using `std::function`, which is nothing like a regular function call.

You can see this by replacing the code in `main()` with this:

```
TestFunc test_func(2);
test_dummy_function(test_func);
test_dummy_function2(test_func.get_ptr());
```

To fix it, simply stop using `std::function`.  You can pass the `TestFunc` object directly by reference or (smart?) pointer.  There should be no need for the hack of casting its address to `size_t` and back again (though note that if you do need to do that, the correct type is `uintptr_t` not `size_t`).

Comment: Yes, I know that std::function is slower than a function call, but I ignored that because its a small diff compared to the overhead of pybind11.  If I run what you suggest, I get:

sum: 705182704 time: 1.255 milliseconds
sum: 705182704 time: 0.268 milliseconds

The original 2 snippets have a diff of 163 millis versus 0.3 millis.  The difference is from the pybind11 wrapper for any cpp functions that have state, i.e. lambdas with captures or function objects, pybind11::cpp_function.  The issue is explained at: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/functional.html

Comment: @sal: OK, but my answer still applies.  Don't use std::function.  Pass a pointer to the class.  Problem goes away.